# Is Mac OS X a UNIX-based OS?

Tags: macos, unix

Is OS X Mountain Lion a pure UNIX-based OS?

Some tutorials say that it is a Unix-like OS, but after version 10.5, all Mac operating systems are based on pure UNIX.

Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of [discussion](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os_x_lion_apples_continuing_unix_dilemma) on this topic, but as far as Apple's [concerned](http://images.apple.com/media/us/osx/2012/docs/OSX_for_UNIX_Users_TB_July2011.pdf), yes it's UNIX:

> Open source UNIX foundation
>
> - POSIX-compliant, Open Brand UNIX 03 Registered Product
> - Open source kernel based on FreeBSD and Mach 3.0
> - 64-bit OS using LP64 data model
> - Support for multiple CPU and GPU cores via Grand Central Dispatch and OpenCL
> - Hand-tuned, standards-compliant scalar and vector math libraries
>
> Standards-based networking
>
> - Complete IP-based architecture supporting IPv4, IPv6, and L2TP/IPSec VPN
> - Rich zero-configuration discovery and naming via Bonjour and Dynamic DNS
> - Interoperable file serving via NFS, AFP, SMB/CIFS, and FTP
> - Powerful Apache web services
> - Open Directory services built on LDAP and Kerberos for single sign-on
>
> Comprehensive UNIX user environment
>
> - Standards-based graphics built on PDF (Quartz), OpenGL, and H.264 (QuickTime)
> - Full-screen terminal with xterm-256color support
> - Familiar UNIX/Linux utilities (such as emacs, vim, and bash)
> - Free Xcode developer tools based on Clang/LLVM

Answer (score 3):

The UNIX trademark is owned by The Open Group, which basically uses it as a certification mark for SUS-compliance. OS X has been [registered as a UNIX 03-compliant product](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/) since 10.5, so it qualifies as UNIX (not just UN*X or Unix-like) in that sense. Most GNU/Linux distributions are not registered as SUS-compliant, so they should be called something like UNIX-like or UN*X in that sense, even though neither of those terms is used by The Open Group.

OS X could also be considered to be [genetic Unix](http://www.catb.org/~esr/hackerlore/sco-vs-ibm.html) in the sense that Darwin was based on FreeBSD (or [it has used FreeBSD as a reference platform](http://macosx.com/forums/unix-x11/29098-how-close-freebsd-darwin-kmod-question.html)), and BSDs are usually considered to be genetic Unix, since the original BSD was based on AT&T code. Both GNU and Linux were rewritten from scratch though, so GNU/Linux platforms are not generally considered to be genetic Unix.

In a functional or spiritual sense, OS X is maybe less Unix (whatever that means) than platforms that are merely "Unix-like" in the first or second senses, but OS X could still considered to "be Unix" in all three senses.